# How to put a limit on the value of attributes Java

Tags: java, object

Example:

```
public class Date {
 private int Day;
 private String Month;
 private int Year;
}
```

How can I do it so in order once a date is set possible values of day may only be from 1 to 31 and month from jan to december, and only those values are accepted.

Comment: Do a validation inside your constructor and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if some argument is invalid.

Comment: Write a setter for each property (setDay(int day), etc.) and call the setters from the constructors. In the setter apply your validation logic.

Comment: that is one of the reasons/advantages of encapsulation: to set a value a method of the class must called = that method can/should test if the value is valid (`if (month < 1 || month > 12) throw new IllegalArgument Exception("month: " + month);`

Answer (score 5):

Since the fields are private, you can check for validness in the setters.  For example:

```
public void setMonth(int month) {
    if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(month + " is not a valid month. Month must be between 1 and 12 inclusive";
    }
    this.month = month;
}
```

Another pattern is the builder pattern, which has a few flavors, including:

```
public Date withMonth(int month) {
    if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(month + " is not a valid month. Month must be between 1 and 12 inclusive";
    }
    this.month = month;
    return this;
}
```

The above have the advantage of creating objects in one line:

```
Date myDate = new Date().withMonth(6).withDate(6).withYear(1976);
```

On another note, it is convention to start variable names with a small letter and use camel casing.  Class names would start with a capital and constants (enums and static finals) should be all uppercase with underscore to improve readability.

Comment: just a little hint : always add the wrong value to the Exception - can help a lot to find the error (e.g. IndexOutOfbounds) [:-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use JEE Bean Validation. Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html):

You can achieve what you want using annotations `@Max` and `@Min`